# Maximum of one exponential and one uniformly distributed random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, convolution

If X and Y are independent random variables with X exponentially distributed with mean 1 and Y uniformly distributed in [0,1] , how do I find the distribution of Max(X,Y)

Comment: People here will be more willing to help if you share what have you tried and where you are stuck at.

Answer (score 0):

$\max\{X,Y\}<x$ if and only if $X<x$ **and** $Y<x$.

It says "and".  And the two are independent.